# Database schema for masseging system as Skype

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm  trying to build web chat with the similar functional as skype has for my pet project, but it's very hard for me to understand how should I build database for chat groups.

Could anybody please show schema of such database or explain how should l relate chat rooms users with messages.

Comment: this question is way to broad. There are hundreds of ways to design your schema. But this shouldn't be your first step. First you need to think of a way to communicate in real time, how to send messages, how to receive messages and how to make sure the right user gets the messages. etc.. the database is merely a background storage for the message-history. Skype for example stores the messages in simple text files on the user's computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes my problem is actually that I couldn't understand how to connect users with the chat room, and I thought that it possible to solve this problem at database level, but the only way I see is to create new tabel with the list of users for every chat room.
As I think it's not a good idea, and it's hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. This is certainly not a solution but it could go into the direction you first intended:

```
+---------------------------------+
|              user               |
+---------------------------------+
- id (INT) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
- name (VARCHAR),
- password (VARCHAR),
- email (VARCHAR),
...  other information ...

+---------------------------------+
|              chat               |
+---------------------------------+
- id (INT) PRIMARY KEY,
- user_id (INT) FOREIGN KEY


+---------------------------------+
|            message              |
+---------------------------------+
- id (INT) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
- chat_id (INT) FOREIGN KEY,
- user_id (INT),
- message (TEXT)
```

Don't get confused with the `keys` and `primary keys`, that's not so important right now. This could work like this:

**1)** every user is identified by his/her `id`

**2)** when a user *1* starts a chat with user *2*, you make two new entries in the chat table:

```
+---------------------------------+
|              chat               |
+---------------------------------+
  id 1,  user_id 1
  id 1,  user_id 2
```

that way user 1 and user 2 share chat 1 together. If you want you can add other user to the same chat

```
  id 1,  user_id 3
```

and so on.

**3)** each message has a unique id and is related to a chat. Since every participant of the chat can see the message you only need to know the user_id who sent it:

```
+---------------------------------+
|            message              |
+---------------------------------+
 id 1, chat_id 1, user_id 2, "hello"
 id 2, chat_id 1, user_id 1, "hi"
 id 3, chat_id 1, user_id 3, "how are you guys!?"
```

and so on.. I think you get the idea :)

Comment: It's seems it will work thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a relational database schema, but as I understand it this type of project may be much better suited to a NoSQL style database (eg Mongo, Couch or Redis), possibly fronted by something like Node.js. Better to get the tool chain right at the beginning than try to change later.
Whichever way you go, you could try downloading an open source web chat solution and just study the code.

Comment: Thank you for advice but doing this project is the way to improve my skills in Python and related technologies . Change technology is not a solution for me.